# pyautogui.hotkey - TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, automation, typeerror, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate some activities, but when I try to use the function hotkey(), an ERROR is detected:

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

# Step 1 - Open the link in a new tab

pyautogui.PAUSE = 1

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','t') #open a new tab
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-2e2b6412b575> in <module>
      6 pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
      7 
----> 8 pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','t') #open a new tab
      9 

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? My teacher used the same code and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as written is accurate. There is nothing programatically wrong with the code you provided:

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','t')
```

Tested on Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], PyAutoGUI version 0.9.53.

Troubleshooting steps that may resolve the issue include restarting your kernel or copying into a new .py or .ipnyb file in order to make sure there is nothing else in your script that may be causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('t')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```